# WPF MVVM: Should WPF namespaces be avoided in 'ViewModel'

Tags: c#, wpf

If we split up the solution into three projects:

View

ViewModel

Model

Should we avoid referencing any assemblies that deal with the 'View' in the 'ViewModel' altogether such as `System.Windows.Controls` or is it acceptable to use properties out of WPF namespaces `System.Windows` such as `Visibility` in the 'ViewModel' project. My worry is that once I reference the WPF assembly in the 'ViewModel' it will be very easy for someone down the road to slip up and do something along the lines of popping up a dialog in the view model code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's typically a good idea to avoid the WPF namespaces and assemblies from the ViewModel entirely.  The ViewModel shouldn't care about the View - and shouldn't be tied to a specific View framework.

For example, if this is done correctly, the same ViewModel would potentially work for WPF as Windows Phone.  If you reference WPF assemblies, this will break.

In your case, the way to avoid referencing `Visibility` would be to just use a boolean, but then use an `IValueConverter` in the XAML to convert from the `bool` (or other ViewModel and normal framework types) to the required View technology you're using (`Visibility.Visible`, etc).